# Определение высоты объекта (например, этажа здания)

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Возможно ли определить аппликату - координату объекта на оси Z - в андроид? Например, определить местонахождение объекта с точностью до этажа здания? Чтобы получилось что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если возможно, то с помощью каких библиотек/алгоритмов?